# The text size on Ubuntu is very small and I cannot see how to change it

Tags: screen, settings

I have just re-installed Ubuntu on a spare machine after some years absence so I may have other questions to come.  My problem now is that my sight is rather poor and the text size on the machine is very small indeed and I cannot see how to change it.  Can you help please?  I am sending this from my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Not an ubuntu answer, but keep your eyes open for a cheap 32in tv to use as a monitor.  Zoom looks/works nicer than on a 15in screen.  Using one that the sound does not work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.  My problem was/is that the text is so small that I cannot read it even my large monitor so your directions will help a great deal. Someone asked about the version which is 18.04.3.

Comment: Thank you, I can now see the text on the screen which is useful.  I still have a few problems so I may be back to you.

Answer (score 2):

In 18.04 go to Settings→Universal Access and set options there such as (for example) set Large Text to ON and Screen Reader to ON.

It is also possible to use Enter Reader View in Firefox by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> which I find extremely useful when reading web pages (being visually challenged myself).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable fractional scaling. Open your terminal and run one of the following command.

If you use Xorg (should be the default):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']"
```

If you use Wayland

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
```

Once set, you can open **Settings** > **Devices** > **Screen Display** to access additional fractional scaling values, including 125% and 150%.

Source : https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/enable-fractional-scaling-ubuntu-19-04

Comment: if I remember correctly.. the second command works for both? am I wrong?

Comment: 0k..the reference you gave it for 19.04..for 18.04 the second command in your answer works..