# Everything is so small in Ubuntu 20.04 running in Thinkpad e14. Is it a driver issue?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, graphics, lenovo, laptop

The texts, windows borders and everything else looks so small except the application icons, I've used Ubuntu before but it was on Desktop and everything looked just fine. I dual booted ubuntu today on my new Thinkpad e14 laptop and it seems that the problem is with display drivers. On additional drivers it showed nothing.

Here are some images to show you how it looks:
[image: file manager ubuntu]

[image: browser ubuntu]

[image: file manager windows]

[image: file manager and browser on windows]

Here is my CPU and graphics deails:

Additional Drivers screenshot:[image]

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          12
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-11
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              6
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      23
Model:                           96
Model name:                      AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 4650U with Radeon Graphics
Stepping:                        1
Frequency boost:                 enabled
CPU MHz:                         1400.000
CPU max MHz:                     2100.0000
CPU min MHz:                     1400.0000
BogoMIPS:                        4192.07
Virtualization:                  AMD-V
L1d cache:                       192 KiB
L1i cache:                       192 KiB
L2 cache:                        3 MiB
L3 cache:                        8 MiB
```

Comment: Check the scaling being used in Windows and set it to the same (or other that feels comfortable) in Ubuntu.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The text size on Ubuntu is very small indeed and I cannot see how to change it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180292/the-text-size-on-ubuntu-is-very-small-indeed-and-i-cannot-see-how-to-change-it)

Comment: It just changes the size of texts, but the window borders and some things in file manager doesn't fixes. It just doesn't feels normal.

Comment: @Mihir does my answer work?

Comment: making it even 125 percent made it worse. Currently I'm managing it just by accesibilty settings "Larger Text."

Answer (score 2):

You will need to enable fractional scaling in Ubuntu.

1. Open display settings.
   [image: activities-display]
2. Enable fractional scaling, and choose the value (e.g. 125% or 150% or something else) that works best for you (you can try one by one).

[image: frac-scale]

Comment: Fractional scaling caused screen to be blurry.

Comment: Did you try both wayland and x.org sessions?

Comment: I'm on 22.04 now which has wayland and the issue still persists.

Comment: You can logout and switch to x.org

Answer (score 1):

1. 'st option: press  <kbd>meta(windows logo)</kbd>, then type
   `settings`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Click `Universal access`. Togle `Large text` on. It will enlarge everything immediately.
2. 'nd option: install gnome-tweaks. Open terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. Run command `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`.
   Run gnome-tweaks: press <kbd>meta(windows logo)</kbd>, then type
   `tweaks`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Click "Fonts". There you will be able to fine-tune font sizes, even scaling factor. Change whatever you like, then logout and login again to apply changes.

Comment: Larger text tweek worked. But in some places it doesn't feel right.

Comment: @Mihir I agree with you, that's why I prefer using gnome-tweaks to change sizes of particular fonts. And even in this case some (rare) applications will not change, since they are using their own fonts or ignoring global system settings.